Defining a new [R package units] scale in UDUNITS-2 syntax
I need to define a new (derived) unit of measure that converts Hz to the psychoacoustic scale Mel

M= 1127*ln(1 + f / 700)

where f is the frequency in Hz (and M the corresponding Mel frequency then).
I am using the R units package, but the units parsing seems to occur in the C code, so I guess solutions in other languages would be helpful.

Assuming you want more than just a conversion function, it looks like you need to modify some XML in the underlying UDUNITS-2 package: "The unit database is encoded using human-readable XML rather than a custom format. The XML parser included in the package supports an  element to allow easy and convenient customization".

See help("install_unit") but I wasn't able to quickly implement it. The main issue is that the parser doesn't seem to support an offset inside a function (i.e., ln).
